# What is wrong with this async-await code (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am very new to asynchronous JavaScript. I am trying to add a new member to a zoo and then display the updated list of zoo animals in the following code. the new animal is being admitted successfully but the method to display updated list of zoo animals is not working. Can anyone plz point out what is going on here?

```
let zoo = [
  { animal: "elephant", age: 15 },
  { animal: "rhino", age: 10 },
  { animal: "tiger", age: 6 },
];

const admit = (animal) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      zoo.push(animal);
      resolve: console.log(
        `new ${animal.animal} added. now ${zoo.length} animals.`
      );
      //reject: console.log("something went wrong");
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const displayZoo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve: console.table(zoo);
      reject: console.log("something went wrong while displaying animals");
    }, 3000);
  });
};

const doSomething = async () => {
  try {
    let admission = await admit({ animal: "lion", age: 13 });
    await displayZoo();

    console.log("everything went fine");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

doSomething();
```

Comment: *What is wrong with this async-await code (javascript)?* you tell us.. is it not working? When I run it its showing `new lion added. now 4 animals.` after 3 seconds

Comment: Is that an object notation inside a function body? That won't work.

Comment: syntax for calling `resolve()` and `reject()` is wrong. Note the `()` used to call them as functions

Comment: choz - that object notation is actually working. charlietfl - I don't understand, should I use () after resolve and reject? It is not working that way either. @Lawrence Cherone - the admit( ) function is working, it successfully adds a new animal Lion, but the display function is not working.

Comment: @charlietfl - hi, thanx, the code is running now (I wrapped code for resolve and reject inside brackets as you said), However, the code for reject is also running. This doesn't seem normal, I want reject code to run only if error happens. should I comment it out?

Comment: You need a conditional to determine whether to resolve or reject, not do both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve` and `reject` in the `Promise` constructor are functions. With async/await syntax, you call `resolve` with the value to return to the function that is await-ing or call `reject` with an object to throw.

Your code is in charge of determining when an error has occurred to decide whether to call `resolve` or `reject`.

```
let zoo = [
  { animal: "elephant", age: 15 },
  { animal: "rhino", age: 10 },
  { animal: "tiger", age: 6 },
];

const admit = (animal) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      zoo.push(animal);
      resolve(`new ${animal.animal} added. now ${zoo.length} animals.`);
      // `await admit()` will return this string ^
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const displayZoo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() > 0.5) { // To simulate some failure condition
          console.table(zoo);
          resolve();
          // `await displayZoo()` will return undefined (void function)
      } else {
          reject('There was an error');
          // `await displayZoo()` will throw this string ^
      }
    }, 3000);
  });
};

const doSomething = async () => {
  try {
    let admission = await admit({ animal: "lion", age: 13 });
    console.log(admission);
    await displayZoo();

    console.log("everything went fine");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks Elan, great explanation!